# Add keyfile for luks encrypted root

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, luks

I have a server running ubuntu 18 and we added the standard LUKS encryption during install. 
It was fine for a while but its become a problem that we can't restart it remotely.

I'd like to add a keyfile for the root partition but I am not sure if this would work.
The boot partition is still unencrypted so we can put it there.

As I said, we have encrypted the root partition `/` so is it even possible to read `/etc/crypttab` before unlocking?

Also, I really dont want to brick the server. Is there anyway to use both a keyfile and a passphrase?

Regards,

Comment: Grub cannot read /boot encrypted so it must be on a plaintext partition. You can put your key file there.

Comment: Actually /boot isn't encrypted so it should be ok to put the keyfile there, but /etc/crontab is, so I am not sure how it wil know where to look

Comment: That's what I was indicating - /boot is _not_ encrypted so that is where the keyfile can be placed. Unclear grammar I guess

Comment: But /etc/crypttab is still encrypted, so how will it know where to look? Also, is there any safe way of doing this which lets you try both keyfile and passphrase?